# Period of an Object in Periodic Motion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, angular-momentum, conservation-laws

[image: A ball of mass M is attached to the end of a string...]

My attempt (if it matters): 
The initial period is given by $T_X = \frac{2\pi X}{v}$ for some $v$. 
The new period is given by $T_Y = \frac{2\pi Y}{v}$ for the same $v$. 
$Y = \frac{X}{2}$, so $T_Y=\frac{\pi X}{v} = \frac{T_X}{2}$

However, the correct answer is $\frac{1}{4}T$. Can somebody explain this to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OP writes in the question formulation(v2):

> *[...] for the same $v$.*

Hint: The speed of the ball is not conserved. Think instead about

1. why the [angular momentum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_momentum) of the ball is conserved, and
2. what angular momentum conservation implies.

Comment: $\omega$ is not angular momentum